# Getting "NoTemplateError: Could not find template" with backbone.marionette

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

In this coffeescript+backbone.marionette application I am trying to write, I am getting a "NoTemplateError: Could not find template: '#second-template' when I try to display a different view in my content region.

Here are the two pieces of code, which are based on [David Sulc's Backbone Books tutorial](http://davidsulc.com/blog/2012/05/06/tutorial-a-full-backbone-marionette-application-part-1/).  The WelcomeApp displays fine but when I click the menu item that then calls MyApp.SecondApp.display(), I get the NoTemplateError.

```
window.MyApp = MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application()

MyApp.addRegions
  menu: '#menu'
  content: '#content'

class MyApp.MenuView extends Backbone.Marionette.View
  el: '#menu'

  events:
    'click #get-second': 'showSecond'

  showSecond: ->
    MyApp.SecondApp.display()

MyApp.vent.on 'welcome:rendered', ->
  menu = new MyApp.MenuView()
  MyApp.menu.attachView(menu)


MyApp.WelcomeApp = do ->
  WelcomeApp = {}

  class WelcomeLayout extends Backbone.Marionette.Layout
    template: '#content_welcome-template'

  WelcomeApp.display = ->
    WelcomeApp.layout = new WelcomeLayout()

    WelcomeApp.layout.on 'show', ->
      MyApp.vent.trigger 'welcome:rendered'

    MyApp.content.show MyApp.WelcomeApp.layout

  return WelcomeApp


MyApp.SecondApp = {}

class MyApp.SecondApp.WelcomeView extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
  template: '#second-template'

MyApp.SecondApp.display = ->
  welcomeView = new MyApp.SecondApp.WelcomeView()
  MyApp.content.show welcomeView

MyApp.addInitializer ->
  MyApp.WelcomeApp.display()
```

My templates are simply script blocks in the index.html.  I actually swapped the template used by the WelcomeApp with that used by the SecondApp and the WelcomeApp can find '#second-template' fine when I do this.

I tried this with both backbone.marionette 0.9.10 and 0.9.11.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your templates are inside `<script>`s but where are the `<script>` elements w.r.t. the rest of the HTML? Inside `<body>`?

Comment: Do we need to read all this code to help you with the issue? is it not possible to recreate the issue in a very sorter code example?

Comment: I'd guess that your templates are inside `<body>` and you're deleting them by saying `$('body').html(some_view.render().el)` to start up your application. All your `<script>`s would be gone after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to both commenters on my question.  While working to strip down the HTML and coffeescript code, I noticed a div in my HTML that was incorrectly closed using `<div>`.  Once I fixed that to a `</div>` everything worked.  Stupid error but I was just not seeing it until I strip down the HTML enough that it was right in my face.  I need better syntax checking.

Comment: Answering my own question following suggestions from original commenters.  Thanks again mu is too short and fguillen.